# After clicking Button app crashes

Tags: android

i added a Login to my App.
Now my starting Activity is the LoginActivity.
Everytime, when i filled in my Account Credentials to enter the App my app is crashing when im clicking on the login Button. This is my error Log:

```
 01-13 15:49:23.752 3116-3408/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_classify_touch NULL, not calling FingerSense
01-13 15:49:23.887 3116-3408/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_touch_up NULL, not calling FingerSense
01-13 15:49:23.923 2475-2475/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
01-13 15:49:23.938 3116-3130/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
01-13 15:49:23.969 3116-3407/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '2f67413 com.example.hartl.main_pp/com.example.hartl.main_pp.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-13 15:49:23.974 3116-3126/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
01-13 15:49:24.005 4043-4187/? E/HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
01-13 15:49:24.018 18188-18208/? E/TotemWeather: WidgetUtils getWidgetShowCityInfo return myLocation
01-13 15:49:24.073 2475-2475/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
01-13 15:49:24.123 2475-2475/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
01-13 15:49:24.262 2475-2475/? E/hwcomposer: setGpuBoost:228: Can't open /sys/class/devfreq/gpufreq/max_freq: Permission denied
01-13 15:49:24.605 2475-2475/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
```

Does somebody know the solution?
Thanks

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback{
    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;

```
private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

private GoogleMap googleMap;

SupportMapFragment sMapfragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());


    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String email = user.get("email");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtEmail.setText(email);

    // Logout button click event



















    sMapfragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);





    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    sMapfragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
            alertBuilder.setMessage("Fine Location is necessary");
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1234);
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1234);
        }

    }





}





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sFm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (sMapfragment.isAdded())
        sFm.beginTransaction().hide(sMapfragment).commit();
    if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
        if (!sMapfragment.isAdded())

            sFm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.penats, sMapfragment).commit();
        else
            sFm.beginTransaction().show(sMapfragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_locations) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_events) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_calendar) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_chat) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_ranking) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

}